# Implementing data.sort to sort json by title, keep getting "undefined" error. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am attempting to sort some JSON data by Title.

Here is the JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "products": null
  },
  {
    "products": {
      "1": {
        "id": "dLJgXNo",
        "title": "BBBBB",
        "image": {
          "url": "https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/google-G-logo-hed-2017.jpg",
          "path": "product_images/ATAzyRGXvIn8I4vTP275Xr3hHowmxhdNMdMDg3Dz.jpeg"
        },
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 1,
        "currency": "USD",
        "stock_warning": 0,
        "type": "account",
        "stock": 13
      },
      "2": {
        "id": "kVq0nNc",
        "title": "LLLLL",
        "image": {
          "url": "https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/google-G-logo-hed-2017.jpg",
          "path": "product_images/C8FFOV9u14AbEALsc6j8YOx68n2ddIxgCBI8T00b.gif"
        },
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 99.99,
        "currency": "USD",
        "stock_warning": 0,
        "type": "service",
        "stock": 9223372036854776000
      },
      "3": {
        "id": "VVPanJG",
        "title": "QQQQQ",
        "image": {
          "url": "https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/google-G-logo-hed-2017.jpg",
          "path": "product_images/ag7cdutbMnSiFknvXi3lKuCHNgCjyo5MEdEic9rS.png"
        },
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 999.99,
        "currency": "USD",
        "stock_warning": 0,
        "type": "service",
        "stock": 9223372036854776000
      },
      "4": {
        "id": "RE3EcTr",
        "title": "AAAAA",
        "image": {
          "url": "https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/google-G-logo-hed-2017.jpg",
          "path": "product_images/Wtu1jGF2FWnxRR00yfvKaKF5Z8jnHrWhVwWUhJzF.png"
        },
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 100
        },
        "price": 0.5,
        "currency": "USD",
        "stock_warning": 0,
        "type": "account",
        "stock": 87
      },
      "5": {
        "id": "oeB4ekE",
        "title": "NNNNN",
        "image": {
          "url": "https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/google-G-logo-hed-2017.jpg",
          "path": "product_images/2X0adruZr4ObIgLujM8LbLzOYiEZxYBuif6K8NnR.jpeg"
        },
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 3,
        "currency": "USD",
        "stock_warning": 0,
        "type": "account",
        "stock": 14
      },
      "6": {
        "id": "17SHtAg",
        "title": "MMMMMM",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1000000
        },
        "price": 1,
        "currency": "USD",
        "stock_warning": 1,
        "type": "account",
        "stock": 5
      },
      "7": {
        "id": "815DuOe",
        "title": "PPPPP",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 3,
        "currency": "USD",
        "stock_warning": 0,
        "type": "account",
        "stock": 15
      },
      "8": {
        "id": "9kRifdb",
        "title": "TTTTT",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1
        },
        "price": 3,
        "currency": "USD",
        "stock_warning": 0,
        "type": "account",
        "stock": 13
      },
      "9": {
        "id": "BoVtpDQ",
        "title": "ZZZZZ",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1000000
        },
        "price": 3,
        "currency": "USD",
        "stock_warning": 0,
        "type": "account",
        "stock": 1206
      },
      "10": {
        "id": "Mb0tcZ6",
        "title": "GGGGG",
        "image": null,
        "quantity": {
          "min": 1,
          "max": 1000
        },
        "price": 2,
        "currency": "USD",
        "stock_warning": 0,
        "type": "account",
        "stock": 998
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I am attempting to use the very handy data.sort function. But only receive the 'localeCompare' of undefined" error. This is my code:

```js
var data = [{"products":null},{"products":{"1":{"id":"dLJgXNo","title":"BBBBB","image":{"url":"https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/google-G-logo-hed-2017.jpg","path":"product_images/ATAzyRGXvIn8I4vTP275Xr3hHowmxhdNMdMDg3Dz.jpeg"},"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":1,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":13},"2":{"id":"kVq0nNc","title":"LLLLL","image":{"url":"https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/google-G-logo-hed-2017.jpg","path":"product_images/C8FFOV9u14AbEALsc6j8YOx68n2ddIxgCBI8T00b.gif"},"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":99.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"service","stock":9223372036854776000},"3":{"id":"VVPanJG","title":"QQQQQ","image":{"url":"https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/google-G-logo-hed-2017.jpg","path":"product_images/ag7cdutbMnSiFknvXi3lKuCHNgCjyo5MEdEic9rS.png"},"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":999.99,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"service","stock":9223372036854776000},"4":{"id":"RE3EcTr","title":"AAAAA","image":{"url":"https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/google-G-logo-hed-2017.jpg","path":"product_images/Wtu1jGF2FWnxRR00yfvKaKF5Z8jnHrWhVwWUhJzF.png"},"quantity":{"min":1,"max":100},"price":0.5,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":87},"5":{"id":"oeB4ekE","title":"NNNNN","image":{"url":"https://www.adweek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/google-G-logo-hed-2017.jpg","path":"product_images/2X0adruZr4ObIgLujM8LbLzOYiEZxYBuif6K8NnR.jpeg"},"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":3,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":14},"6":{"id":"17SHtAg","title":"MMMMMM","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1000000},"price":1,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":1,"type":"account","stock":5},"7":{"id":"815DuOe","title":"PPPPP","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":3,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":15},"8":{"id":"9kRifdb","title":"TTTTT","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1},"price":3,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":13},"9":{"id":"BoVtpDQ","title":"ZZZZZ","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1000000},"price":3,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":1206},"10":{"id":"Mb0tcZ6","title":"GGGGG","image":null,"quantity":{"min":1,"max":1000},"price":2,"currency":"USD","stock_warning":0,"type":"account","stock":998}}}];
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.products.title.localeCompare(b.products.title);
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Surely I have to be missing something here, am I missing a loop somewhere? Maybe I am not navigating the JSON correctly. Anything helps and is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `a.products.title.localeCompare(b.products.title);` doesn't work with the structure of your data. Notice that `products` is an *object* with key/value pairs. The values have a `title` property, but the `products` object does not, hence `a.products.title` and `b.products.title` are both `undefined`, and trying to do `undefined.localeCompare` will fail.

It seems to me that you're actually wanting to pull the products out of the `products` object first and then sort them. Try this:

```
const sortedData = data
  .reduce((products, obj) => products.concat(Object.values(obj.products || {})), [])
  .sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jacob, it is greatly appreciated. You really couldn't have explained it better. I didn't know you could reduce the json, this is SO much easier for me to grasp.  I am confused about the sortedData constant although, what is the purpose of this? Thanks

Comment: That's just there so when you do your `document.write` you'll have something to call your `JSON.stringify` on, like `JSON.stringify(sortedData)`.